# Masonry Views can't load masonry effect in D7

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-masonry

I had installed Masonry Views module, along with Masonry module in my Drupal 7 site.
In my view, I can select format as "Masonry", and had updated the details such as column width.
But the output still displays the view like unfomatted list.

In my status report, it shows
jQuery Masonry 2.1.08
jQuery Update   jQuery 1.10.2

My js file is in: www/mydomain/sites/all/libraries/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js

I had flushed cached, but the masonry effect still doesn't appear. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find out what it was ?

Comment: What theme are you using? I have now *ZEN 5 responsive* and just got it working.

Comment: I'm using adaptive theme for drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again I have a silight suspicion what the problem might be: are your content items display literally *as a list*? Then you might have to adjust their **widths** first so more than one can fit inside your content container – otherwise they'll be listed *as a list*.

So for example if your content container is 960px wide, you should add / modify something like this to your theme's stylesheet, adjusted to your personal preferences of course:

for the container:

```
.my-container-view #content { 
    width:960px; 
}
```

for the items:

```
.my-container-view .item { 
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
```

The `float` might be redundant since masonry should take care of that – but this is at least what I have in my stylesheet…